# Notifying data change from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-listview

I have a problem. I have two activities(MainActivity, EditAccount).
In the MainActivity i compiled a listview from a database.
And in the EditActivty, i updated data into the database and came back to MainActivity as soon as the data was changed with this:

```
    public class EditAccount extends Activity {
    ......
    ......


    public void update_acc(View view){

    EditText accName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.acc_name);
    EditText comment=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.comments);
    String acc_name=accName.getText().toString();
    String comments=comment.getText().toString();
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    int id = (int) intent.getExtras().getLong("data_id"); 
    String data_id= Integer.valueOf(id).toString();

    datasource.updateEvent(acc_name, comments, data_id);
    datasource.close();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Account updated; Acc_name:"+acc_name+", Comment:"+comments, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The problem is that when the Activity redirects back to MainActivity, the data is not updated there in the ListView. So, how can I notify the ListView that the data has been changed?
Please help.
Thanks in advance,
Waiting for your reply...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are filling your ListView from database inside `onCreate()` possibly. So, solution is to fill the ListView with database inside `onResume()` that will fetch the updated data from the database.

Because when you return back to MainActivity its `onResume()` will be called, so just put your code for fetching data from database inside `onResume()` instead of `onCreate()` and update your ListView.

Comment: can you please tell me how i can execute the Oncreate() method inside the onResume() method.

Comment: No need to do that, just put your code for fetching data from database and setting Adapter inside `onResume()` thats it

Answer (score 0):

set data inside onResume() instead of onCreate()

please go through the complete Activity Lifecycle.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score -1):

Add this `youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: its not gonna work. i have to notify from one activity to another

Comment: this code will only execute it if the adapter is present in that very activity